# Shortcode for Custom Field of Media Attachment (to use with Featured Images)

Tags: custom-field, shortcode, advanced-custom-fields, media, attachments

I'm using ACF (Advance Custom Fields) for Media Uploads to store location information about photos. When I set a post Featured Image to a photo that has this extra field, I'd like to output the location information from this Custom Field.

Basically, I need a shortcode that will output an ACF Custom Field of the Current Post's Featured Image.

Comment: Your best bet is to ask the ACF developers how to go about doing this; ACF works different than standard WP and WPSE is intended for development/programming questions that are directly within WordPress and not third party methods.

Comment: I contacted the ACF developers who said to hire a freelancer

Answer (score 0):

The most basic option I can think of is this

```
add_shortcode('bt_featured_image_acf_location', 'bt_featured_image_acf_location');
function bt_featured_image_acf_location ($atts) {
    return get_field('location', get_post_thumbnail_id());
}
```

Change 'location' to your acf field name and thats it.

`get_post_thumbnail_id()` will get the current post featured image id.

Once you have the ID of the post (images are posts, they are of the post type, attachment) that you want to get the ACF fields from you can pass it to `get_field()` in the second argument and you're done.

Change it how ever you want and add as much logic as you need, this is the best I can do with the information you provided

> EDIT

If you use this shortcode inside a post template `single.php`, this shortcode works fine.

If you would like to display it anywhere else you will need to pass the post id manually.

Below the edited shortcode that can accept post id

```
add_shortcode('bt_featured_image_acf_location', 'bt_featured_image_acf_location');
function bt_featured_image_acf_location ($atts) {
    $atts = shortcode_atts([
        'post_id' => get_the_ID()
    ], $atts);

    return get_field('location', get_post_thumbnail_id($atts['post_id']));
}
```

Now this shortcode will still work the same way, but now you can pass it the post id

regular way to call it

`echo do_shortcode('[bt_featured_image_acf_location]')`

call the shortcode with post id

`echo do_shortcode('[bt_featured_image_acf_location post_id="5526"]')`

Comment: Tried this but can't get it to work. You mention once I have the ID it can be passed to get_field(), but empty is for current post ID, right? And nothing else should be needed?

Comment: Edited my answer to include a "new" shortcdode that can accept the post id as attribute

Comment: Super appreciate your help! I think my setup is introducing some additional complications. If you're willing to do some hired help, put a link in your bio so I can reach out!